# How do I repair this tile without removing it

Tags: repair, tile, crack

How do I repair this bathroom tile without removing it. I have do not have any extra tiles to use.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You don't repair it, you patch it, and don't use the toothpaste. I have seen repairs done with a small bead of caulk. You can rub it in good and then clean up the tile. This looks like hell. You could also use some white or clear acrylic nail polish and carefully go over the cracks. The problem is someone probably cracked that tile by kicking it and it could crack again. The tile might not be supported properly.

I know you said you didn't have any spare tiles but this is a pretty common tile so take some measurements and head out to a tile warehouse and look for a match and fix this right. Also, the grout is missing on the lower left corner and I would think there should be a caulk bead between the wall and floor.

Comment: It depends on what is behind the tile.   Also if this has a full pan with a lip, you do not need to caulk the bottom.

Comment: @DMoore You might not need to but most installers I know, do. That's usually a cut edge and might not be as straight as the adjacent tiles so caulk covers that up. plus, you still wouldn't want any moisture getting in there.

Comment: Thanks, @JACK I'll try that.

Comment: @CraigHB - if that isn't in a shower, look to replace it.   I honestly wouldn't touch it in a shower.   The waterproofing should be behind it and I don't see a lot (if any) water getting in those cracks.